# la opcion editor.formatOnType de settings.json no me funciona con prettier en vscode

Tags: php, javascript, formato, vscode

Estoy configurando el formateador [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) en mi proyecto, estoy tratando de trabajar con el archivo de configuración "**.prettierrc.json**", específicamente quiero utilizar la opción del editor vscode "**editor.formatOnType**" del archivo **settings.json** (para **user**), de manera que mientras estoy escribiendo código, vscode lo formatee al pasar de linea, pero como dice la pregunta, no funciona.

Cuando la opción "**editor.formatOnSave**" esta establecida a *true*, ésta si funciona correctamente formateando todos los archivos tal cual esta descrito en "*.prettierrc.json*" cuando guardo el/los archivo(s) editado(s). Incluso utilizando prettier a través de su **CLI** también funciona correctamente, es decir, lo siguiente en bash funciona:

> prettier --write archivo.js

Todas las opciones que probé, descritas en la pagina de [Prettier (opciones)](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html) me han funcionado con el **CLI**. El **CLI** lo instale rápido y sin problemas, como se describe en [Prettier (Install)](https://prettier.io/docs/en/install.html), con el comando:

> npm install --global prettier

Instale la extensión de Prettier para vscode tal cual se describe en la pagina de [Prettier (editors)](https://prettier.io/docs/en/editors.html). El hecho de que vscode formatee el código cuando la opción **editor.formatOnSave** se establece a *true*, me da a entender que la extensión esta bien instalada en vscode.

Nunca coloco ambas opciones al mismo tiempo en *settings.json*, solo las he cambiado para pruebas pero realmente la que me interesa es **editor.formatOnType**.

Acá les dejo mi archivo **.prettierrc.json** (sencillo)

```
{
    "tabWidth": 4,
    "semi": true,
    "singleQuote": true
}
```

Acá les dejo mi archivo **settings.json**

```
{
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
    "editor.matchBrackets": false,
    "workbench.colorCustomizations" : {
        "editorLineNumber.activeForeground" : "#ffffff",
        // "editorCursor.foreground" : "#ffffff"
    },
    "bracketPairColorizer.showBracketsInGutter": true,
    "bracketPairColorizer.showBracketsInRuler": true,
    "bracketPairColorizer.activeScopeCSS": [
        "borderStyle : solid",
        "borderWidth : 5px",
        "borderColor : {color}; opacity: 0.5",
        "backgroundColor : {color}"
    ],
    "bracketPairColorizer.highlightActiveScope" : true,
    "bracketPairColorizer.scopeLineCSS": [
        "borderStyle : solid",
        "borderWidth : 2px",
        "borderColor : {color}; opacity: 0.7"
    ],
    "highlightLine.borderWidth": "1px",
    "highlightLine.borderStyle": "solid",
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
    "[git-commit]": {
        "editor.rulers": [
          50
        ]
    },
    "workbench.editor.showTabs": true,
    "window.menuBarVisibility": "toggle",
    "better-comments.multilineComments": true,
    "workbench.activityBar.visible": false,
    "breadcrumbs.enabled": true,
    "editor.occurrencesHighlight": true,
    "highlight-matching-tag.styles": {
        "opening": {
            "left": {
                "custom": {
                    "borderWidth": "0px 0px 0px 3px",
                    "borderStyle": "solid",
                    "borderColor": "red",
                    "borderRadius": "5px"
                }
            },
            "right": {
                "custom": {
                    "borderWidth": "0 3px 0 0",
                    "borderStyle": "solid",
                    "borderColor": "red",
                    "borderRadius": "5px"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

}